# Is is possible to set per file custom metadata in dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to be able to set custom metadata on a file in dropbox.  Ideally a string of at least 32 bytes for each file.  I've looked through [the core API docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs) but I haven't seen a way.

However I'm new to Dropbox so maybe I missed something or there is another way?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403857/how-to-update-an-attribute-or-a-key-for-a-file-while-saving-it-in-to-documents-d

Comment: @MarkSetchell That is certainly in the same direction.  The only answer indicates using extended attributes on the files, but that wouldn't work for me as I don't want to modify the source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any way to set additional metadata on the file for your app. You could use the Datastore API (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore) to store the string and the associated file path.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a go with the datastore.

Comment: "The Datastore API has been deprecated. The official date of retirement for the Datastore API is April 29th, 2016." :-(